# Can we dynamically create an object by checking existance?

Tags: java, object

For the following class I want to access an object if the name equals to something, let's say "you". Otherwise I want to create it.
I want to check if an object exists that has the name as 'you' and then add entries to the ArrayList contInstances. If such an instance doesn't already exist I want to create it. Next time I might have to use the same object so that I can add some more entries to the ArrayList.

```
public class Values {
    String name;
    ArrayList<anotherClass> classInstances = new ArrayList<anotherClass>();
}
```

This happens to be in a loop. How can I do that?

Edit: I'll quote an example here:

```
if (an object exists that contains field 'name' == 'YOU'){
add entries to the array list directly using the available object
}
else {
create a new object and set the 'name' = 'YOU';
add entries to the array list;
}
```

Comment: Objects don't generally have names. In particular, a *variable* is not an *object*. Now if you've got a class which has a `getName()` method or something similar, that's a different matter. Or perhaps you want to have a `Map<String, AnotherClass>` to associate names with objects. Either way, please clarify the question.

Comment: You just have a method that checks whether the object is present, and if not, it creates one, adds it, and returns it.

Comment: Please clearify what you want to do? What do you want to compare ?

Comment: @JonSkeet The `Values` class has a `name` member - presumably this is what the question is referring to.

Comment: Unrelated note - most Java coding standards dictate that class names should start with a capital letter (i.e. `AnotherClass`, not `anotherClass`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds kind of like you want to have a cache by name.  Instead of an `ArrayList`, consider using a `Map<String, AnotherClass>` to keep track of Name->Object mappings.

You can then use this approach:

```
Map<String, AnotherClass> instances = new LinkedHashMap<String, AnotherClass>();
for (...) {
    String name = getNextName();
    AnotherClass instance = instances.get(name);
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = makeInstance(name);
        instances.put(name, instance);
    }
    useInstance(name, instance);
}
```

After that loop is finished, if you still want a `List<AnotherClass>`, you can use `return new ArrayList<AnotherClass>(instances.values());`